# Better performant quad-tree for moving and colliding objects

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine, data-structures, quadtree

So basically I want to make a scene where around 50K Asteroids are spawned with a position and AABB (Axis Aligned Boundry Box) and move each one of them to a random direction which is generated in the beginning. After moving them around I have to check if any of the Asteroids are colliding.

I am using Quad-Tree data-structure for insertion and checking for collision.
I keep an array of 50K points and iterate over and update them then insert in Quad-Tree and iterate again over 50k points and query through QT to see if any of the points are colliding.

I have read a lot here and there for about 2 weeks and tried as many sources as I could but I can't squeeze out max performance. Most sources are using c++ or other better performant languages, but I need to make it using C#. Any kind of advice for improving performance would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
public struct Point
{
    public float x,y; 
    public int ID;

    public void MoveTowards(float posX, float posY)
    {
        position.x = position.x + posX;
        position.y = position.y + posY;
    }
}

public class Controller
{

    Point[] asteroids = new Point[50K];
    Point[] speed = new Point[50K];
    QuadTree qt = new QuadTree();

    //Runs every frame
    void Update() 
    {
        qt.ClearAllNodes();
        for loop asteroids(50K)
        {
            asteroids[i].MoveTowards(speed.x, speed.y);
            qt.Insert(astetoids[i]);
        }

        for loop asteroids(50K)
        {
            int collidingAsteroidID = qt.Query(astetoids[i]);
            if(collidingAsteroidID != -1) { 
                print(collidingAsteroidID + " is colliding with " + i); 
            }
        }
    }

}

class QuadTree 
{
    public Rectangle boundry;
    Point[] nodes;
    bool root = false;
    bool divided = false;
    int numberOfNodesInserted = 0;
    QuadTree northEast, northWest, southEast, southWest;

    public QuadTree(Rectangle boundry) 
    {
        nodes = new Point[4];
        this.boundry = boundry;
    }   

    #region Methods

    //Clear all the nodes in the Quad-Tree
    public void ClearAllNodes() 
    {
        if(numberOfNodesInserted == 0 && !root) return;
        numberOfNodesInserted = 0;
        root = false;

        if(divided) 
        {
            northEast.ClearAllNodes();
            northWest.ClearAllNodes();
            southEast.ClearAllNodes();
            southWest.ClearAllNodes();
        }
        divided = false;
    }

    public bool Insert(Point point) 
    {
        //Checking if the position is in the boundries.
        if(!boundry.Contains(point)) return false;
        if(numberOfNodesInserted < 4 && !root) 
        {
            nodes[numberOfNodesInserted] = point;
            numberOfNodesInserted++;
            return true;
        }
        else if(root)
        {
            if(northEast.Insert(point)) return true;            
            if(northWest.Insert(point)) return true;        
            if(southEast.Insert(point)) return true;
            if(southWest.Insert(point)) return true;    
        }
        else if(!root && numberOfNodesInserted == 4)
        {
            //Making this node a branch and moving all the to sub-leafs 
            root = true;
            numberOfNodesInserted = 0;

            if(!divided)
                SubDivide();

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                if(!northEast.Insert(nodes[i]))         
                if(!northWest.Insert(nodes[i]))     
                if(!southEast.Insert(nodes[i]))
                if(!southWest.Insert(nodes[i])) { }
            }

            if(!northEast.Insert(point))            
            if(!northWest.Insert(point))        
            if(!southEast.Insert(point))
            if(!southWest.Insert(point)) { }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int Query(Point point, float radius)
    {

        if(numberOfNodesInserted == 0 && !root) return -1;
        if(!boundry.Contains(point)) return -1;

        if(!root && numberOfNodesInserted != 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfNodesInserted; i++)
            {
                if(DoOverlap(nodes[i], point, radius)) 
                    return nodes[i].ID; 
            }
        }
        else if(root && numberOfNodesInserted == 0)
        {
            int result;
            result = northEast.Query(point);
            if(result != -1)  return result;

            result = northWest.Query(point);
            if(result != -1)  return result;

            result = southEast.Query(point);
            if(result != -1)  return result;

            result = southWest.Query(point);
            if(result != -1)  return result;
        }
        return -1;
    }
    #endregion

    #region HelperMethods
    private void SubDivide() 
    {
        //Size of the sub boundries 
        if(northEast == null) 
        {   
            float x = boundry.x;
            float y = boundry.y;
            float r = boundry.radius / 2;

            northEast = new QuadTree(new Rectangle(x + r, y + r, r));
            northWest = new QuadTree(new Rectangle(x - r, y + r, r));
            southEast = new QuadTree(new Rectangle(x + r, y - r, r));
            southWest = new QuadTree(new Rectangle(x - r, y - r, r));
        } 
        divided = true; 
    }


    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some data how fats your implementation is and how fast it needs to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About your implementation:

It seems like you are rebuilding the whole tree for every step. Is this necessary? If you move a point, they will often stay in the same node, so you could avoid clearNodes() and and subsequent insertion into the same node.

Other implementations:

I have implemented some spatial indexes in Java, with insertion/update rates of around 1M points/sec and query rates (collision checking) of 100,000 per second (assuming that there is usually around 0 or 1 collision per point. See some performance measurements [here](https://github.com/tzaeschke/TinSpin/blob/master/doc/benchmark-2017-01/Diagrams.pdf) (Figure 16b for 3D queries and Figure 40b for updates).
The fastest are quadtrees (see [qthypercube and qthypercube2](https://github.com/tzaeschke/tinspin-indexes/tree/master/src/main/java/org/tinspin/index)) and the [PH-Tree](https://github.com/tzaeschke/phtree).
They all use z-order navigation as described [here](https://github.com/tzaeschke/phtree/blob/master/Z-Ordered_Hypercube_Navigation.pdf) (self advertisement). One part of this is that it calculates the correct sub-nodes during navigation/insertion/update/deletion. For example, when calling insert(element) on a node, it quickly does not try out all subnodes, but 'calculates' which sub-node is correct and directly calls insert() on that sub-node.

Answer (score 3):

New answer with additional requirements:

Okay, so with 50K points and 120Hz you need to do 50,000*120=6,000,000 collision checks per second. Considering that a CPU with 4GHz, this means you have around 650 CPU cycles per collision check. I don't think you can do this with quadtrees or anything similar, even with the most efficient programming language.

I see only one options: 
Since you are using 2D, try the following: Sort all points by their X-coordinate. Then march through all points and check for collision with all point that are close enough on the X-coordinate that they may have caused a collision. Such an algorithm has some advantages:

- It is much more cache-friendly than spatial indexes, and cache misses (memory access) are most likely the bottleneck.
- It is easily parallelizable (sorting can be mostly parallelized and search can be mostly parallelized).
- It is simple enough that it can probable be executed on a GPU.

One a single CPU core, this is still likely to be too slow. But using an 4 core machine you may get the desired frame rate. Using a GPU, it may be possible to get even much more than what you require. However, I have no experience with using GPUs, so I don't know how (easy) this can be done.